# Questions Per Day - Needs work

Tags: discussion

There are 90 days left before Public Beta period is end but the 'Question per day' is still not healthy. What will happen if this situation continues when the Public Beta day ends?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The public beta started in April 2014.

From the relevant metrics the questions per day is the most concerning.

I see only a couple of action points, which any of us can do:

- kindly inform the users via a comment that is is better to ask the question on StackExchange.
- do not answer any Joomla-related questions on Stackoverflow
- flag valuable questions to be moved to the Joomla Site (can be done by an SO moderator)
- actively ask new questions and maybe also give the answer to the problems you currently face

Answer (score 2):

We should definitely work to improve those statistics, but at the same time I don't think it's too much to worry about. A couple of months ago a [post was published on SE Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites), addressing the issue of beta sites:

> The TL;DR:
>
> When a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll
>   consider it for graduation. If a public beta site does not produce
>   consistently helpful content, and lacks the caretakers needed for
>   flags and spam to get handled and our Be Nice policy to be upheld, it
>   will be closed. Is your site in between these two categories? You
>   don’t have anything to worry about. Regardless of how small the site
>   might be, you have a home here in the SE network. Spoiler alert: As of
>   this post, no site which is currently active is at risk of being shut
>   down.

Right now, the site has **4.8** questions per day, this seems to vary quite a bit. The unanswered questions queue seems to be growing slowly, but I've seen many people putting lots of effort into making JSE a nice and clean site.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you hear about `90 days left before Public Beta period`? I remember reading a post ages ago about the new structure for Beta sites but can't remember it all.

Indeed the questions per day isn't doing well. The problem being is that there are lots of people out there still using Stack Overflow or the Joomla forum for support.

Only thing we can really do about the Stack Overflow user is ask them to post their question on JSE instead.

As for the Joomla forum users, I can ask to see if some sort of notification could be put on there, advertising JSE.

Comment: in here http://i.imgur.com/wxzONXE.png

Comment: Ah ye. That's an older message that's displayed from the beginning of a Beta site. It doesn't mean we have 90 days left of Beta ;)

Answer (score 1):

Well for me the number of daily questions is a metric somewhat expected. Although if we manage to bring the questions that arrive in StackOverflow into here - and when I have the chance, I try for it - the daily questions metric will rise up, I still believe keeping a high number of quality and unique questions is a bit hard, while the topic is the same.

The topic will expand as Joomla is progressing and changing, with new features, new possibilities etc. Otherwise, there will be a point where almost everything will have been asked and replied.

So daily questions is not actually in our control... and we can't do much when Joomla users don't have that many questions non-answered already, here (or elsewhere). 
Ok, probably questions will continue with their pace and so Joomla, will keep on progressing.

Whatever the case, what we can probably do, is to improve what it's already in our hands...
Clean up questions/answers, answer questions with no answers, post alternative answers to questions with some answers.